# Python websocket server is running on port but portchecker.co says port closed

Tags: python, websocket, port

So I have a Python web socket server that runs on my server's port 8080. It is a Ubuntu 20.04 server that uses ufw (Uncomplicated Firewall) for its firewall.

I typed:
`sudo ufw allow 8080` to open the port 8080 on my system, and then started the python server. Now the thing is that my Python websocket server has been started but when I go to https://portchecker.co and type my server IP + port, it says that `port 8080 is closed`, even though the server is started and the port is opened via ufw.

To test this more, I tried starting an http server with port 80 opened and checked it on https://portchecker.co and voila, it says that `port 80 is opened`.

This is my Python Websocket server's code:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import random
import string
import subprocess
import os
import logging
import ssl
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()

logging.basicConfig()

ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)

ssl_cert = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/edlivon.com/fullchain.pem"
ssl_key = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/edlivon.com/privkey.pem"

ssl_context.load_cert_chain(ssl_cert, keyfile=ssl_key)


async def write_audio(websocket, path):
    audio_data = await websocket.recv()
    folder = "audios"
    filename = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=12))
    file_format = ".wav"
    output_path = folder + "/" + filename + file_format

    with open(folder + "/" + filename + ".webm", "wb") as f:
        f.write(audio_data)

    subprocess.run(["ffmpeg", "-i", folder + "/" + filename + ".webm",
                   "-acodec", "pcm_s16le", "-ar", "48000", output_path])

    with sr.AudioFile(output_path) as source:
        audio = r.record(source)

    result = r.recognize_google(audio, language="en-US")

    os.remove(folder + "/" + filename + ".webm")
    os.remove(output_path)

    response = result
    await websocket.send(response)


async def server(websocket, path):
    await write_audio(websocket, path)


start_server = websockets.serve(server, "localhost", 8080, ssl=ssl_context, origins="*")


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

To start the websocket server, I simply run `python3 app.py` and I have all the dependencies of this script installed and working properly, running the script produces no error. Can anyone help me out with fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

maybe they have a firewall between you and the internet

you could test by opening a separate session in the server and trying to connect to your script locally

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have a dedicated server so I control the firewall. As I said, I used `ufw` to open port 8080 with the websocket server and it shows port closed but when I tried port 80 with a **web** server, it showed port open.

Answer (score 0):

A kind human being just told me that I should replace `localhost` with `0.0.0.0` and suddenly, it works.